# Count down not betwen two dates

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, countdown, countdowntimer

Need help to customize this script

```
 <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){             
                $('.demo4').dsCountDown({
                    startDate: new Date("December 11, 2020 12:12:29"),
                    endDate: new Date("December 12, 2020 12:12:29"),
                    theme: '',
                    titleDays: 'd',
                    titleHours: 'h',
                    titleMinutes: 'm',
                    titleSeconds: 's'
                    ,onFinish: function(){ 
                    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'get_update.php'
            });
            setTimeout(function(){
            window.location = "index.php?go=stake"; 
            }, 3000);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

How to change the time between those 2 dates to a single value

```
startDate: new Date("December 11, 2020 12:12:29"),
endDate: new Date("December 11, 2020 12:17:29"),
```

I want with single value, etc 5 minutes not betwen two dates like startdate - enddate

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you're looking for? The comments you've made in the answers are confusing. Where would this single value come from?

Answer (score 0):

```
var diffMs = (startDate - endDate);
var diffDays = Math.floor(diffMs / 86400000); // days
var diffHrs = Math.floor((diffMs % 86400000) / 3600000); // hours
var diffMins = Math.round(((diffMs % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000); // minutes
console.log(diffDays + " days, " + diffHrs + " hours, " + diffMins + " minutes)");
```

Comment: sorry, I mean, I don't want to use startDate - endDate
I want to be like for example: countdown for 5 minutes
so no countdown between 2 dates but a 5 minute countdown
thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by substracting Dates Objects and get that diference in miliseconds, then you can use a function to get seconds, minutes, hours or days from that miliseconds number, try this:

```js
var dates = ["December 11, 2020 12:12:29", "December 11, 2020 12:17:29"];
var fechas = [];

for(let i = 0; i < dates.length; i++){
    fechas.push(new Date(dates[i]));
}
console.log(fechas);

function convertMiliseconds(miliseconds, format) {
  var days, hours, minutes, seconds, total_hours, total_minutes, total_seconds;
  
  total_seconds = parseInt(Math.floor(miliseconds / 1000));
  total_minutes = parseInt(Math.floor(total_seconds / 60));
  total_hours = parseInt(Math.floor(total_minutes / 60));
  days = parseInt(Math.floor(total_hours / 24));

  seconds = parseInt(total_seconds % 60);
  minutes = parseInt(total_minutes % 60);
  hours = parseInt(total_hours % 24);
  
  switch(format) {
    case 's':
        return total_seconds;
    case 'm':
        return total_minutes;
    case 'h':
        return total_hours;
    case 'd':
        return days;
    default:
        return { d: days, h: hours, m: minutes, s: seconds };
  }
};

var milisecondsDiference = fechas[1] - fechas[0];
console.log(convertMiliseconds(milisecondsDiference, 'm'));     //Output 300 seconds
```

Comment: sorry, I mean, I don't want to use startDate - endDate
I want to be like for example: countdown for 5 minutes
so no countdown between 2 dates but a 5 minute countdown
and use my script above
thank you for your answer :)